# Save my own class as an array in Parse

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, save

I have a class named Pet.  I collect it in an array.  Then I try to save it like below code. I also tried inheriting NSObject to the Pet class with no use.  Is it not possible to save my own class of arrays in Parse or am I doing something really wrong?  Note that the current user exists and valid.

Somewhere in code defined:

```
var pets : [Pet] = [Pet]()
```

populated:

```
pets.append(newPet)
```

and tried to save:

```
@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    PFUser.currentUser().setObject(pets, forKey: "pets")

    user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            DLog("Suceess saving")
        } else {
            displayAlertWithTitle(self, nil, error.description)
            DLog(error)
        }
    })
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
2015-02-17 18:28:59.906 Patikoy[38292:2121589] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Patikoy.Pet)'
```

p.s. I am a beginner in Swift as well as Parse. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse is likely trying to serialize the "pets" array into JSON. However, your "Pet" class is not serializable to JSON.

From the [NSJSONSerialization Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html):

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> - The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> - All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray,    NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

You need to create a method on your Pet class that converts it to a Dictionary, as described in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9893370).

Comment: Hmm. I need to dig in a little deeper. The example is Obj-C, I wish it were in swift. Thanks though, my search was empty, now I have something to work with.