# Swift array of String:AnyObject dictionary to json api endpoint

Tags: arrays, json, swift2, network-programming

I am working on this issue since days.

I need to send an object as paramenter to an api endpoint. Is expected to me to send a JSON array of objects with this format.

```
[
    {name:"SomeName", lastname:"Some LastName", address:"watheaver"},
    {name:"AnotherName", lastname:"Some LastName", address:"watheaver"},
    {name:"AnyName", lastname:"Some LastName", address:"watheaver"}
]
```

I already have the object parsed to JSON ussing a swift library called "JSONCODABLE" or similar, however if I make an array of those objects and try to serialize the array to JSON I get the error (I dont get any error serializing only the object)

example code

```
    let tratamientos:NSArray = [try! tratamiento.toJSON() as! JSONObject]
    let tratamientosArray = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(tratamientos, options: []) --> error: Invalid top.level type in JSON write.
```

What I do next with NSData...

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url.SYNC_TRATAMIENTOS)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue(auth["UUID"], forHTTPHeaderField: "UUID")
    request.HTTPBody = tratamientosArray
```

Can you please help me figure it out...

Note: I have reads several post regarding how to parse JSONArrayData to array but not the other way around.

###### edit

after doing a lot of testing here you have my findings .

```
//VALID JSON OBJECT I CAN SEND IT TO AN API
let tratamientos = try! tratamiento.toJSON() as! JSONObject
let tratamientos = try! tratamiento.toJSON() as! JSONObject


INVALID OBJECT ALWAYS SENDING NIL NOT GIVING ANY ERROR
let tratamientos = [try! tratamiento.toJSON() as! JSONObject]
let tratamientos = try! tratamiento.toJSON() as! JSONObject
```

The only diference is the array closure. The object that I want to be contained in an array have arrays also... I can parse that object so I can parse a class or struc that have only one parameter type array but as I am not the owner of the api endpoint I cannot change its structure and I need to send a JSON array like this

```
[
    {one:1},
    {two:2}, 
    {thre:3}
]
```

insted of this

```
{ numbers:[
    {one:1},
    {two:2}, 
    {thre:3}]
}
```

How can I send an array like this instead of an object

Comment: So what's your issue?

Comment: My issue is that I cannot get a properly formated JSON array to send to the api. I have several individual json formated objects, i need to know how to serialize an array of objects to json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with NSJSONSerialization - Invalid type in JSON write (Menu)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893217/error-with-nsjsonserialization-invalid-type-in-json-write-menu)

Comment: I have realized that I was doing the conversion to nsdata two times that was the reason for the error. Now I get no error but I am ending up with a bad  formatted JSON array.